# How can I mark everything within brackets, quotes, etc.?

Tags: mark

Please dont suggest `expand-region`. It regularly expands onto symbols which I don't intend to  mark. I am looking for a way instead to simply mark all the text within matching delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if this describes something you've already rejected, but we
sometimes overlook the most obvious solutions.

For all of the below examples, point needs to be in front of the
opening bracket, quote, or parenthesis.  If point is located inside of
the pair, the easiest way to get it in place is usually to press
"C-M-u", but this depends on what command your major-mode has bound to
that key.  It also depends on the major-mode's syntax-table (which you
can update if necessary).

## Marking the surrounded text

For example in `emacs-lisp-mode`, if you have a line like this:

> (message |"The best things in life are free.")

(where "|" is the location of point.)

You can mark the text inside of the quotes like so:

1. C-M-SPC
2. C-f
3. C-x C-x
4. C-b

Even though this is 4 keystrokes, I find it satisfying in its
efficiency and predictability.

If you're using the QWERTY layout, all base keys are on the left-hand
side, the result being that you can use one hand to hold control and
meta, while the other hand presses the letters.

This becomes a quick movement after you've done it a few times, and
the results are more predictable than `expand-region`.

## Alternatives to marking the text

If you already know what you'd like to do after marking the text, you
can probably reduce the number of keystrokes by avoiding that step
entirely.

### Deleting or killing the inner text

To delete or kill/cut the inner text and insert something else inside
the pair of punctuation marks, you can just delete everything and
replace the pair.

1. C-M-SPC
2. C-d to delete, or C-w to kill
3. "

- `electric-pair-mode` automatically places the closing quote after the
  cursor.
- If `delete-active-region` has been set to `nil`, then "C-d" won't work
  to delete, so you'll need to use "C-w" to remove the text regardless.
  (The default value for that variable is `t`.)

Another option is to use `zap-to-char` or `zap-up-to-char`.  (The
latter has no default keybinding, but "C-z" is a popular one to use,
since it matches the M-z binding of the former.)

You could do:

1. C-f
2. M-z
3. .

If there are multiple periods in the text, you can repeat the last two
keypresses until you've killed everything (or use "M-k" until only the
last period remains, then use "M-z .").  The text will be joined
together on the kill-ring.

Or, you can use `zap-up-to-char`, if you've bound it to "C-z".

1. C-f
2. C-z
3. "

### Replacing the paired punctuation

If you want to replace a surrounding pair with a different type of
pair (e.g. parentheses to brackets) the `delete-pair` command may be
useful.  This is another command that has no default keybinding, but "C-c d" is a good place for it.

Given the same example text and point location above, you could
replace the parentheses with square brackets in the following manner.

1. C-M-u
2. C-M-SPC
3. [
4. C-c d

(with "C-c d" bound to `delete-pair`)

Comment: thanks a lot for this informative answer. I try to see what works for me. However, C-M-SPC for me just insert a blank character oO

Comment: Well that's strange, because the default binding of C-M-SPC is `mark-sexp` since version 22 at the latest (but probably before that).  You can see what command it's currently bound to by entering C-h k C-M-SPC.